# Go Get Request - write: broken pipe

Tags: go, tcp, gorilla

I'm Sorry in advance for the probably stupid question.
I want to send an image(image/jpeg) when certain URL is called. When I do few get request everything seems  to be working fine, but when I use apache benchmark to stress test the same endpoint I got this error

> write tcp [::1]:8080->[::1]:65255: write: broken pipe

Here is a code I want to execute:

```
func CameraImage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //log.Println("Serving", r.URL)

    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")

    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    path := vars["camera_path"]

    camera := getService().GetByPath(path)

    if camera.Image == nil {
        return
    }

    err := jpeg.Encode(w, camera.Image, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c19c9c6f797d744382a90f35f8ea512f

https://github.com/babell00/toc_camera

Thanks for any Help
Kuba

Comment: What does the cpu (wait) do?

Comment: this method  camera := getService().GetByPath(path) returns camera object from map

Comment: It kinda looks like the client might disconnect before receiving the response.

Comment: Don't use `ab`. It's `http/1.0` and probably not even using keepalive. Chances are you've just exhausted your ephemeral ports or file descriptors on the server.

Comment: I think you are right, and ab is the problem. Thanks

Comment: Try using https://github.com/rakyll/hey instead of AB.